# Results reproducibility with Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

do results in solr/lucene are reproducible given a static set of indexes?

If I run the same query twice at different times, or if I run the same query on 2 different instances with the exact same indexes, will I obtain the same results, or will caching and other factors will influence the rankings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the exact same index, the results should be identical for deterministic queries (remember that *queries* can be dependent on the time of day, etc.). Otherwise pagination etc. would behave weirdly.

But this assumes that all the factors are *exactly the same* - the same index, the same Solr version, the same underlying JVM (I'm sure there are differences here as well).